# checking type of child when argument is passed by base class pointer

Tags: c++

I have one base `B` and its 2 derived (`D1`, `D2`) classes that look like this

```
struct B
{
   virtual B* DoSomething()=0;
};

struct D1:public B
{
   B* DoSomething()
   {
      // D1 does something
      return pD1;
   }
};

struct D2:public B
{
   B* DoSomething()
   {
     // D2 does something
     return pD2;
   }
};
```

and now I have a function

```
void Init(B*pB)
{
   if(pB is D1)
   {
      D1* pD1=down_cast(pB);
      pD1->MethodD1();
   }
   else if(pB is D2)
   {
      D2* pD2=down_cast(pB);
      pD2->MethodD2();
   }
   else
   {
      //do something else
   }
}
```

I don't want to check types in `Init()` method like this but don't know what else I can do.

Comment: How about making `MethodD1` and `MethodD2` the same method from `B`, that both `D1` and `D2` override ? If you really want to explicitely dispatch instead, your answer is `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Are you looking for [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) or [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)?

Comment: Maybe you want to look into http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Comment: typeid is a bad suggestion. The correct solution is using virtual methods properly.

Comment: @Quentin:The problem with virtual method is that Init() receives a B*. So it can't tell which class overriden method, D1 or D2

Comment: @Ripi2 that's how virtual methods work. The call is automatically dispatched to the correct implementation, regardless of the static type of the object.

Comment: @Quentin You're right in case `Init()` receives a derived pointer. Not the OP case. He needs `dynamic_cast` or other approach as shown in answers.

Comment: @Ripi2 No, really, that's the whole point of virtual functions. For example, he can also call `pB->doSomething()` inside `Init()` and it will dispatch to the correct implementation depending on the dynamic type of `*pB`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your `Init()` method not in pseudo code:

```
void Init(B*pB)
{
   if(D1 *pD1 = dynamic_cast<D1*>(pB))
   {
      pD1->MethodD1();
   }
   else if(D2 *pD2 = dynamic_cast<D2*>(pB))
   {
      pD2->MethodD2();
   }
   else
   {
      //do something else
   }
}
```

As you can see dynamic_cast return `nullptr` if the type of the derived class is not the one you are casting for.

You can do this also using references, in that case dynamic_cast returns an exception if the type is not the one you are casting, so, since exception handling is not free it's always better to use pointers for dynamic cast purpose.
Please note also that this is a runtime check, not a compile time check.

Answer (score 1):

really you should be doing

```
struct B
{
   virtual void Init();
   virtual B* DoSomething()=0;
};

struct D1:public B
{
   B* DoSomething()
   {
      // D1 does something
      return pD1;
   }
   void Init()
   {
      MethodD1();
   }

};


struct D2:public B
{
   B* DoSomething()
   {
      // D2 does something
      return pD2;
   }
   void Init()
   {
      MethodD2();
   }

};
```

and in your main code

```
void Init(B*pB)
{
   pB->Init();
}
```

thats the whole point of encapsulation, inheritance, virtual methods, etc.